# Missing the following properties from type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web

Hello I have this piece of code in TypeScript

```
 var btn  = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-up") as EventTarget;
 btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 console.log('clickcc');
})
```

And It throws me this error
*  Type 'HTMLCollectionOf' is missing the following properties from type 'EventTarget': addEventListener, dispatchEvent, removeEventListener *

Please how to fix it?

Comment: I fixed it with document.getElementById selector, but if I want to bind more buttons, how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will returns the `array` of elements, not just a single element :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-up") as EventTarget
```

To :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-up")[0] as EventTarget
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-TS-EventTarget]

Comment: That doesn't work  " Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'EventTarget[]': pop, push, concat, join... "

Comment: @BrokolicovýDžuß, it's working please check working demo